# Using OutputDebugString in the code is making the compilation fail when built in release mode.(VC++)

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, release, outputdebugstring

I have used OutputDebugString @ many placed in my VC++ code. Its building fine in debug mode. But using the same code with OutputDebugString is making the compilation to fail.

How to avoid this build failure in RELEASE mode even while using "OutputDebugString" in the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `OutputDebugString` is fine in Release builds.  Something else is wrong.  What is the exact error message the you are getting?

Comment: Release builds will simply ignore OutputDebugString(). Perhaps you are using an argument to OutputDebugString() that is defined only for Debug builds?